# MediaStore.Audio album art database update

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

AFAIK, the album art files are places at the loacation `Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs`.

For a newly dowloaded song, when I query the database `MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` for the field `MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART`, the value is null. However I am getting the name of the album correctly, which implies the row has been inserted, but value of this field is not updated.

However if open a default music player, I can see that it is able to load this album art. Can someone please explain, why the query returns null to my app?

Comment: there is a typo MediaStore.Audio.Albumbs.ALBUM_ART it should be MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART

Comment: Yes..corrected that..typo not there in code.